# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to5π/4}(1-\tan(x))\sec(x)$. Can anyone explain?

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to5π/4}(1-\tan(x))\sec(x).$$

How do I solve this problem? Can anyone explain?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This can just be evaluated by "direct substitution", that is, insert $ \  x = \frac{5 \pi}{4} \ $ .  Neither tangent nor secant do anything peculiar at that value of  $ \ x \ $ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the facts that $\;\tan(\pi+x)=\tan x$, $\;\sec(\pi + x) = -\sec x,\;$ and $\;\dfrac {5\pi}{4} = \pi + \dfrac \pi4$:

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x\to 5π/4}(1-\tan(x))\sec(x) & =  (1 - \tan (5\pi/4))(\sec 5\pi/4)\\ \\ & = (1 - \tan(\pi + \pi/4))(\sec(\pi + \pi/4))\\ \\ & = (1 - \tan(\pi/4))(-\sec (\pi/4)) \\ \\ & = (1 - 1)(-\sqrt 2) \\ \\ & = 0\end{align}$$

Comment: Nicely formatted too +1

Answer (score 0):

As $\tan(\pi+y)=\tan y,\tan\frac{5\pi}4=\tan\frac\pi4=1$

As $\sec(\pi+y)=-\sec y,\sec\frac{5\pi}4=-\sec\frac\pi4=-\sqrt2$